# Favicon "cannot be displayed because it contains errors"

Tags: .htaccess, favicon

I have a favicon.ico linked to my site.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://nameofsite.com/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

However, you'll notice that when you visit, you get the error message:

> The image "link-to-image" cannot be displayed because it contains errors.

I tried uploading the favicon.ico file to another server, and it loaded without any problems.
Which leads me to believe perhaps my htaccess file is affecting it?

In my htaccess file, I make sure to add rules that exclude anything dealing with the 'ico' extension, so that the ico file can be viewed.
Some rules include:

```
# SITE NAVIGATION

    # Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    # such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    # request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule !\.(css|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|txt|xml|js|pdf|html)$ /root/to/public_html/nameofsite.com/index.php [NC,L]

# ANTI-HOTLINKING

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?nameofsite.com(/)?.*$ [NC]
    RewriteRule .*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|bmp|png|ico|css|js|pdf)$ http://nameofsite.com [R,NC]
```

However, I cannot find any errors with these rules.
Any suggestions are welcome, I'm kind of at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

Try reuploading your favicon.ico file, it is empty:

```
$ curl -i http://thejadednetwork.com/favicon.ico
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 19 Dec 2013 10:15:00 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Mon, 24 Sep 2012 01:13:21 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: image/x-icon
```

Another suggestion, this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?nameofsite.com(/)?.*$ [NC]
```

would also match `http://nameofsite-com.example.com/`. You probably meant:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?nameofsite\.com(/|$) [NC]
```

Comment: The file does exist - triple checked it, about 1.12kb.  I even downloaded it from my live server via FTP.  Which was why I was wondering about the htaccess.

Comment: I also tried replacing it with a different favicon.ico file from another site that works fine, but I still get the same problem.  It is definitely not the file.  For now though, I found a workaround by changing it to favicon.png instead of .ico.  It still doesn't solve the mystery though.